# how to have fullwidth of two columns in a same line

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

when my screen is more than 700px , how can I have my two columns in the same line ?

- a right column with a max-width of 600px and a left column with the rest of the screen ?

when the screen is less than 700px 
- i would like to have my two column with 100% width, one above the other

**HERE IS MY UPDATED JSFIDDLE**:  www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/uwkbn5nd/6/

Comment: the code was edited, here is my link http://www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/uwkbn5nd/6/

Comment: you need to remove %20 @eranotzap

Comment: Try adding some code, a working FIDDLE will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style>
#right {
 width:600px;
 height:100px;
 float:right;
 background:#8f8;
}
#left {
 height:100px;
 margin-right:600px;
 float:none;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#ff8;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
#right, #left {
 margin:0;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
}
}
</style>
<div id="right">
Some text for the right column
</div>
<div id="left">
Some text for the left column
</div>
```

But it works if the right column has fixed width:600px but not max-width:600px

Comment: I updated mine with a part of your idea, did you think is okay -> http://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/uwkbn5nd/8/

Comment: I don't know for the Result window at jsfiddle has width less than 700px. Try to create a simple test.html page on your PC

Answer (score 0):

I would do this.

```
div.fullwidth{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0 600px 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
div.left{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#f00;
}
div.right{
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#0f0;
}
@media (max-width:700px){
    div.fullwidth{
        padding:0;
    }
    div.right{
        position:relative;
        right:auto;
        top:auto;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

and wrap the .left and .right elements (I've used classes, you can use ID's ofcourse), in a parent element.

```
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

this gives you the behavior you want.